# How can I save crawling(scraping,streaming) result?

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, stream, web-crawler

crwaling(scraping,streaming) result is very good

ex. 973 : {'text': 'RT @1111: hihihihihihi' }

BUT! Unable to save.

How do I fix it?

```
import tweepy
import time
import os
import json
import simplejson

search_term = '5555'
search_term2= '4444'
search_term3='3333'
search_term4='2222'
search_term5='1111'

lat = "11.11"
lon = "11.11"
radius = "100km"


API_key = "0"
API_secret = "0"
Access_token = "0"
Access_token_secret = "0"

location = "%s,%s,%s" % (lat, lon, radius)

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_key, API_secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access_token, Access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

c=tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                q="{}+OR+{}".format(search_term, search_term2, search_term3, search_term4, search_term5),
                rpp=1000,
                geocode=location,
                include_entities=True)

data = {}
i = 1
for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    time.sleep(0.4)
    i += 1
```

txt file is not made. ->There is no error message.

Or, txt file is made. but, there is no "tweet text and tweet date" in the txt. ->There is no error message.

(Not necessarily a txt file.Save Excel file.)

```
wfile = open(os.getcwd()+"/tqtq.txt", mode='w')   
data = {}   
i = 0       

for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    data['date']= tweet.text 
    wfile.write(data['text','date']+'\n')  
    i += 1
    time.sleep(0.4)
wfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using pickle

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(obj, filename)
```

To load it back `result = pickle.load(filename)`